# Can I reuse jobs count in Makefile recipes?

Tags: shell, makefile

For example when I call

```
make -j9 build
```

And in *Makefile*

```
build:
    stack build --jobs $(jobs)
```

I want to have jobs=9.

Comment: in short, yes, you can

Comment: possible duplicate of [GNU make: Extracting argument to -j within Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303553/gnu-make-extracting-argument-to-j-within-makefile)

Comment: I can see only "-j --jobserver-fds=3,4", but not the "-j9".